# To-do app with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I`m currently writing a simple vanilla JavaScript to-do application.Everything looks fine , but when it comes to saving the data in the new localStorage , I can't make it , I've never used localStorage , I've read a lot of articles , when I try simple stuffs it works , but I can't make my application work properly. I want to save the entered data so on REFRESH , it won't disappear , the way it is now... here's the link to the application

**** I WANT TO DO IT WITH VANILLA JAVASCRIPT , NOT JQUERY ****

[My to-do app here!](http://codepen.io/nasco/pen/MJpozg)

So basically , if the user make several todos , and when refresh , I want everything to stay , like in the image blow.

[image]

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div class="holder">
        <div>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <button id="add">Add</button>

        <div class="results"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

        let holder = document.querySelector('.holder'),
            addBtn = document.querySelector('#add'),
            removeBtn = document.querySelector('#remove'),
            resultBox = document.querySelector('.results');

        let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];


        function setAttributes(element,attrs){
            for(let i in attrs){
                element.setAttribute(i,attrs[i]);
            }
        }

        setAttributes(input,{
            'placeholder' : 'Enter To-Do',
            'name' : 'todo'
        });

        function addtoBtn(){

            addBtn.addEventListener('click',function(event){

            if(input.value !== ''){
                let openingDiv = '<div class="todo"><span>';
                let closingDiv = '</span><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="save">Save</button><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></div>';

                resultBox.innerHTML += openingDiv + input.value + closingDiv;
                input.value = '';
                event.preventDefault(); 


            } else{
                alert('Enter To-do!');
            }

            let innerBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn');
            let editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
            let saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.save');

            for(let collection = 0 ; collection < saveBtn.length ; collection++){
                saveBtn[collection].style.display = "none";
            }

            function removeToDo(){

                this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            }

            for(let k = 0 ; k < innerBtn.length ; k++){
                innerBtn[k].addEventListener('click',removeToDo);
            }

            function startContentEdit(){
                this.previousSibling.contentEditable = true;
                this.previousSibling.style.padding = "10px";
                this.previousSibling.style.boxShadow = "0 0 15px #fff";
                this.previousSibling.style.borderRadius = "10px";
                this.previousSibling.style.transition = "all .4s";

                this.style.display = "none";

                for(let el = 0 ; el < saveBtn.length ; el++){
                    this.nextSibling.style.display = 'inline-block';
                }
            }

            for(let j = 0 ; j < editBtn.length ; j++){
                editBtn[j].addEventListener('click',startContentEdit);
            }

            function saveContentEdit(){
                this.style.display = 'none';

                for(let j = 0 ; j < editBtn.length ; j++){

                    this.previousSibling.style.display = "inline-block";

                    this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.display = "block";
                    this.parentNode.firstElementChild.contentEditable = false;
                    this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.padding = "0px";
                    this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0";
                }
            }

            for(let x = 0 ; x < saveBtn.length ; x++){
                saveBtn[x].addEventListener('click',saveContentEdit);
            }

            }); 
        }

        addtoBtn();
});
```

As I said ,  I saw many articles ,but I cannot find any answer to my solution.
Sorry but that's my first javascript application which is almost everything working in it :D and I`m kinda excited , so I want to make it fully working.

Resume:

Is it possible with localStorage or sessionStorage , to save the new generated

`<div class="todo></div>` containers?

Comment: Storing *HTML elements* rather than the data behind it sounds like a bad idea. This is a *lot* of code, arguably too much for a Stack Overflow question. Can you clarify in more detail what you are stuck with, and show the code relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using local storage is pretty simple actually:
get yourself a reference:

```
store = window.localStorage;
```

then you can store things in it like you would with any other container for key-value-pairs:

```
store[<key>] = <value>; //or alternatively:
store.setItem(<key>, <value>);
```

and to retrieve the values again:

```
val = store[<key>]; //or alternatively:
val = store.getItem(<key>);
```

to save your javascript objects as strings in the storage i'd suggest using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() like this:

```
store.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
todos = JSON.parse(store.getItem("todos"))
```

here the 'todos' can be pretty much anything *without* a circular reference since this would confuse the JSON parser ;>

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project, here is a sample code to save html to the local storage

```
var myToDos= document.getElementById('myToDos');
var htmlHolder = { "htmlToDo": myToDos.outerHTML };
localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(htmlHolder ));
```

You can retrieve it using this

```
var myStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStorage'));
```

In order to load the html elements, you need to make use of the DOMParser, and then append it to your work area.

```
var parsedHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myStorage.htmlToDo, "text/html");
```

Please take note that "text/html" will return an entire html source code with the headers and body, get your needed element by inspecting the output on the console and accessing the relevant children using .lastElementChild and such. Since your containers are probably going to hold lots of children, all you have to do is loop through the .children node lists.

I'm telling you it is completely possible, as I have done it myself on a rather desperate condition. But be aware, localStorage is very small and is only around 4-10mb-unlimited depending on the browser quota.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

    let history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoHistory")) || [];

        addBtn = document.querySelector('#add'),
        removeBtn = document.querySelector('#remove'),
    resultBox = document.querySelector('.results');

        let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];


        function setAttributes(element,attrs){
            for(let i in attrs){
                element.setAttribute(i,attrs[i]);
            }
        }

        setAttributes(input,{
            'placeholder' : 'Enter To-Do',
            'name' : 'todo'
        });

    function applyNewEntry(entry){
        if(input.value !== ''){
            let openingDiv = '<div class="todo"><span>';
            let closingDiv = '</span><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="save">Save</button><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></div>';

            resultBox.innerHTML += openingDiv + entry + closingDiv;
            event.preventDefault();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function addtoBtn(){

        addBtn.addEventListener('click',function(event){

        if(applyNewEntry(input.value)){
            history.push(input.value);
            input.value = '';
            localStorage.setItem("todoHistory", history);
        }
        else{
            alert('Enter To-do!');
        }

        let innerBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn');
        let editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
        let saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.save');

        for(let collection = 0 ; collection < saveBtn.length ; collection++){
            saveBtn[collection].style.display = "none";
        }

        function removeToDo(){

            this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        }

        for(let k = 0 ; k < innerBtn.length ; k++){
            innerBtn[k].addEventListener('click',removeToDo);
        }

        function startContentEdit(){
            this.previousSibling.contentEditable = true;
            this.previousSibling.style.padding = "10px";
            this.previousSibling.style.boxShadow = "0 0 15px #fff";
            this.previousSibling.style.borderRadius = "10px";
            this.previousSibling.style.transition = "all .4s";

            this.style.display = "none";

            for(let el = 0 ; el < saveBtn.length ; el++){
                this.nextSibling.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
        }

        for(let j = 0 ; j < editBtn.length ; j++){
            editBtn[j].addEventListener('click',startContentEdit);
        }

        function saveContentEdit(){
            this.style.display = 'none';

            for(let j = 0 ; j < editBtn.length ; j++){

                this.previousSibling.style.display = "inline-block";

                this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.display = "block";
                this.parentNode.firstElementChild.contentEditable = false;
                this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.padding = "0px";
                this.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0";
            }
        }

        for(let x = 0 ; x < saveBtn.length ; x++){
            saveBtn[x].addEventListener('click',saveContentEdit);
        }

        }); 
    }

    addtoBtn();
});
```

You'll need to implement some kind of UUID system for your entries, probably saving the uuid into the dom via a data attribute, that way you can edit/delete them fairly easily.

Basically, what I'm illustrating is that there's no reason to save the DOM. just JSON.stringify the important stuff (the text inside) and save that. Then rehyrdrate it from the local storage on reload.

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KamOxw)